# Can actuator monitor Apache Httpclint Pool?

Tags: spring-boot

buddies, I'm using Apache Httpclient in my spring-boot project. Can I monitor the connection pool metrics of HttpClient through the Spring-Boot-Actuator? Does actutor already support ApacheHttpclient monitoring?
Thank you so much for helping me!

Tell me does actutor already supported, and show me the code where/how does it dow if already supported